# Как "сплющивать" div внутри flex, чтобы родитель не растягивался?

Tags: html, css

Есть div со свойством flex, внутри еще 4 div'а с контентом(текст) по вертикали и по центру. Как сделать, чтобы при масштабировании div'ы с контентом сжимались, а родитель не растягивался по высоте?

```css
.sliderContent {
  clear: both;
  height: 550px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.sliderContent-upperText {
  width: fit-content;
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.18px;
}

.sliderContent-dash {
  width: 80px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.sliderContent-middleText {
  width: fit-content;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-top: 74px;
}

.sliderContent-shortcuts {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 64px;
}

.sliderContent-shortcuts-round {
  margin: auto 6px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderContent">
  <div class="sliderContent-upperText">Nunc eget nibh</div>
  <div class="sliderContent-dash"></div>
  <div class="sliderContent-middleText">Morbi in nisl auctor</div>
  <div class="sliderContent-shortcuts">
    <div class="sliderContent-shortcuts-round">
      <img src="images/facebook-logo.png" alt="face">
    </div>
    <div class="sliderContent-shortcuts-round">
      <img src="images/twitter-logo.png" alt="twit">
    </div>
    <div class="sliderContent-shortcuts-round">
      <img src="images/wifi-logo.png" alt="wifi">
    </div>
    <div class="sliderContent-shortcuts-round">
      <img src="images/vk-logo.png" alt="vk">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Comment: Текст так просто сжиматься не будет. Нужно либо с помощью медиа-запросов уменьшать размер шрифта (чтобы текст оставался в одной строке и не переносился), либо делать текст на svg

Comment: спасибо - понял)

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно с помощью калькуляции сделать резиновый шрифт пример: calc(10px + 0.5vw)

Comment: и как это должно работать применительно к заданному вопросу?